# Android Studio causes Windows 8.1 to crash

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

Ever since I updated my PC to Windows 8.1, when I start Android Studio and run a simple app I'm testing with, I get a  :(  with a "critical_structure_error" that forces my core i7 to restart!

I cleaned out all temp files using CCleaner after I noticed my disk was 100% in the task manager, but that didn't seem to fix much (even though I cleaned 16G out!).

When I open Android Studio again, I get a bunch of errors like this:

> Cannot load settings from file 'C:\Users\Me\.AndroidStudioPreview\config\options\feature.usage.statistics.xml': java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected content storage modification File content will be recreated

If I leave AS open, it just keeps popping up the same type of content storage error until I close and reopen AS. Once I reopen, I can see the project and it builds fine.  Seems like at this point, if I open the emulator, that's when I get the blue screen with :(

I'd really like to keep Windows 8.1 and the current 0.5.9 version of AS without having to revert back to Win 8 or another AS version.  More importantly, I don't want my PC to crash every time I use Android Studio!?!  Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: AS is in "Early Preview" mode, could be a bug they haven't fixed yet...

Comment: Have you tried reverting to AS 0.5.8 to see if the problem persists? At least that would tell you whether the problem is with 0.5.9 or with Windows 8.1.

Comment: I've seen this 0.5.4-0.5.9.  I'm trying to monitor the processes that are running to get my disk usage up to 100%??  I don't see anything out of the ordinary running...

Comment: @Code-Guru fixed that pesky AS crashes the whole system thing, checkout the answer below

Comment: @Blaine AS pushes updates so often I thought it was a bug with recent versions, but it turned out to be a Windows 8.1 issue, check out my answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out it's a Windows 8 issue with the available virtual memory.  It seems like a few new processes (like Superfetch) eat up a ton of processing power to constantly scan your drive for changes, so searching is faster.

The solution is to change the min and max virtual memory values.  Here's how to do that:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-virtual-memory-size#1TC=windows-7

I have 7GB of memory so I set the min to 2000MB and max to 5000MB.  Haven't had a crash all day!

Comment: Isn't there a way to disable processes like Superfetch?

Comment: @NickFlekerFelker sure, but then you're disabling some core Windows functionality, which might not be a solution for some users

Comment: Yeah, you have a good point. Anyway, your solution worked for me, so kudos.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how your computer is setup, you may need to start as administrator. I need to because the computer has certain permissions installed by Corporate security. Of course your JDK_HOME and PATH should be setup as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you are using Windows 8.1 Enterprise. The reason for this is probably that you took the free upgrade option from Windows 8. If that is so, then you will have to find a way to revert to Windows 8, hopefully from a backed up version that you have on a CD.