# How to resolve runtime exceptions when loading a project in Android studio 1.0?

Tags: java, android, exception, io, android-studio

When I tried starting an Android project in Android Studio 1.0 on Windows 8.1 that I previously created, this is the exception(dialog I am getting) [image]

And this is the error when i get when i exit out of the first exception dialog. This one repeats itself 
[image]

Does anyone know what the issue is? I don't understand how there is an unexpected content storage modification exception when I am just loading the project.

I tried changing memory values but my system doesn't allow you to -  [Android Studio causes Windows 8.1 to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026139/android-studio-causes-windows-8-1-to-crash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's having the same issue, I don't what happened but when I followed the advice that the second answer on this thread - [Android Studio causes Windows 8.1 to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026139/android-studio-causes-windows-8-1-to-crash-) gave, which is to run as administrator, my project loaded up fine.